# GWT-2.1 против GWT-2.0: новинки, которые вам понравились

Tags: gwt, java

Расскажите, что из нового в GWT-2.1 вам понравились и что еще хотелось бы видеть в GWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Понравилась возможность использовать logging и безопасный html, а также то, что открыли много методов для использования (которые раньше были внутренними и приходилось писать подпорки). Но не нравится, что почти на всё Warning: deprecation.

Хотелось бы видеть:

1. Метрики текста (Font Metrics)
2. Продвинутый tabbed pane - чтобы можно было располагать табики хоть снизу, хоть сверху, хоть сбоку.
3. Возможность делать menu item неактивным.
4. Возможность применять атрибуты, содержащие "-".

Comment: Font Metrics уже давно пора бы сделать. А то на данный момент некоторые библиотеки на основе GWT предлагают считать метрики, но там это делается через дикий workaround, когда в рутовую панель добавляется невидимый элемент с текстом, а потом считают длину этого элемента

Answer (score 2):

Мне понравилось то, что включили в коробочную поставку инфраструктуру построения приложения по MVP-подходу. На текущем проекте в силу исторических причин приходится использовать стороннее решение. В будущем, при старте новых проектов буду смотреть только на коробочные решения.
Также понравился RequestFactory, но опять же, только по описанию и по helloworld-исследованию. На практике пока не довелось попробовать